# Is it possible to embed android source code (native app) into phonegap app?

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, native

Is it possible to embed android source code (native app) on phonegap app?
in this case, I want to embed a part from the source code.

If it's possible, is the a tutorial about it?

I know that android use java and phonegap based on html5, and javascript.

or maybe Is it possible if i reverse the condition, embed phonegap into native app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use native code of choosen platform via plugins. Also in case of building native app you can create a WebView and work with web technology inside it. 
If you want to build your own plugin, start with something simple: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/